# React with TypeScript: how to create ref prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic4, react-props, react-proptypes

I am using Ionic with React (typescript) and I am creating my custom form builder. There I created my form that has to have a ref property, because I need a reference of it when I use it.
My problem is that I don't know how to define a prop that is reference type for my custom form builder.

This is how I am using it:

```
const form = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);

return (
  <IonPage>
    <Header />
    <IonContent fullscreen>
      <Form
        ref={form}
        submit={() => onSubmit()}
        fields={ fields }
        render={() => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <IonCard>
              <IonCardHeader>
                <IonLabel>Valamilyen form</IonLabel>
              </IonCardHeader>
              <IonCardContent>
                <Field {...fields.name} />
              </IonCardContent>
            </IonCard>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}/>
    </IonContent>
    <Footer />
  </IonPage>
);
```

Here I got an error:
*Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IFormProps & IFormState & { children?: ReactNode; }'*

My Form React.FC looks like this:

```
type formProps = IFormProps & IFormState;
    
export const Form: React.FC<formProps> = React.forwardRef<HTMLFormElement, formProps>( (props: formProps, porpsRef) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate={true} ref={porpsRef} />
  );
)};
```

I need to add to my Form component a property named ref of the reference, but I don't know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think there is small mistake. Can you please try this

```
type formProps = IFormProps & IFormState;

export const Form: React.FC<formProps> = 
React.forwardRef<formProps, HTMLFormElement>( (props: 
formProps, porpsRef) =>
{
   return (
       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate={true} ref= 
      {porpsRef} />
    );
 )};
```

Comment: I think that is not correct, but I tried, and that's not good.

Comment: No, it's counter-intuitive but `forwardRef` actually puts the generic for the ref before the generic for the props.

Answer (score 1):

I just typed [a very long answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64488719/how-to-use-forwardref-with-functioncomponent-in-react-native-using-typescript/64491870?noredirect=1#comment114040498_64491870) to a similar question.  In your case you seem to be making only one of those mistakes, which is declaring your `Form` as `React.FC`.  The `FC` interface isn't aware of the ref forwarding that you've added with `React.forwardRef` so that's why you get an error when trying to pass a prop `ref` to it.

Delete this bit `: React.FC<formProps>` and you should be fine.  You've already typed the generics on the `React.forwardRef` function, so typescript will know the return type and apply it to `Form`.

```
export const Form = React.forwardRef<HTMLFormElement, formProps>(...
```

If you wanted to explicitly declare the type, you can do that but it's a mouthful.

```
export const Form: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<formProps & React.RefAttributes<HTMLFormElement>> = ...
```

(also you've forgotten to destructure `handleSubmit` from `formProps`)