# How to use forwardRef with FunctionComponent in React Native using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I've looked at many of the docs and examples but I still can't seem to quite understand how to use `forwardRef` with a functional component with TypeScript in React Native. Below is an example where I create a `MyCustomComponent` with a custom function that I try to call from the parent by creating a ref. However, since the ref is incorrectly defined and `null`, I obviously get an error message telling me that the function doesn't exist. Please help me understand how to properly use `forwardRef` in React Native. Thanks in advance!

```
interface MyCustomComponentProps {
  title: string
}

const MyCustomComponent: React.FunctionComponent<MyCustomComponentProps> = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const coolAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert('Hey!', 'This was called from MyCustomComponent')
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.title}</Text>
    </View>
  )
})

export default function App () {
  const MyCustomComponentRef = useRef()
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <MyCustomComponent ref={MyCustomComponentRef} title='Hello World' />
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          MyCustomComponentRef.coolAlert()
        }}>
        <Text>Click Me</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Comment: I had to revert back to using `classes` for now but if anyone knows the answer to using Functional Components I would love to know!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Forwarding the Ref

Refs can be really confusing because there are multiple ways to handle them and because people aren't aware of the difference between the ref object (`React.MutableRefObject` or `React.RefObject`) and the ref value, which is stored on the `.current` property of the ref object.  You've made that mistake here, along with some missing or incorrect typescript types.

`useRef<T>` is a generic hook where the value `T` tells up what type of value will be stored.  We need to tell `App` that we intend to store something with a `coolAlert` method.  Actually we'll see later on that we need our ref to be immutable so we we'll use `createRef<T>` instead.

```
interface MyRef {
  coolAlert(): void;
}

const MyCustomComponentRef = createRef<MyRef>();
```

When we call `onPress`, we need to access the current value of the ref object.  By adding the generic to `createRef`, typescript already knows that this value is either `MyRef` or `undefined`.  We can call `coolAlert` with the optional chaining `?.` operator.

```
onPress={() => MyCustomComponentRef.current?.coolAlert()}
```

Now we need to do some work on `MyCustomComponent`.  You've erred by assigning it the type `React.FunctionComponent<MyCustomComponentProps>` because a function component doesn't have the knowledge about ref forwarding that we need.

```
function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(Component: RefForwardingComponent<T, P>): ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>;
```

The type for `MyCustomComponent` should be that complicated return type from `forwardRef`.  But we don't need to assign that type ourselves, we just need to pass the generics `T` and `P` to the `forwardRef` function call.  `T` is the type of the ref and `P` is the type of the props.

```
const MyCustomComponent = React.forwardRef<MyRef, MyCustomComponentProps>(...
```

Ok so we [got rid of all the typescript errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBXAZyWQDNs0pUZikSBfOEqCEOAIkvRjYG4BYAFChIsXADVgSAO7YAyihJIAgpwnTsAFQh40ACxQAjADZIA8mHTAYAT01IAHjAZMW7ThgC0AOxQxgANyReQUFgL2ooEnQkOABZawBhQhgWBJZILyRwgAVmMAJcQThiuD8YEwAuOAIYKDCAc0E6EKFwpEjouOtSQoFitAgIIyUTWAAKAEoq-whgABN%20AWaBQQGvGq6kmtT0iEzwuABeRFQMADoSaCkUKDnSAB540mx4rZSQNPA9rJhciHyAHxjMZgPIEbCUEgTI4A3olOBrDYDIYjdrwY6TGFw%20ElFCjGBjADkGl0wAK1wKaDxJjmjGYrFeyR2X32MEJE0W8OW8MoMDwUC8cDGRRxxXuaikAJFovh9w0DhgAJwoP%20BDOZRMdHuAHp5Y4pX0ZTqJQb4RMmuaVgIHCJ4HNaCg8EZ4CQ8F4MMA9nAlGAwELoThpQi9htGdsPrtWT1jhQqDQSI9urQgRyg7z%20YLhYbRfd5IoVKgTUGZXBE29mRkfnBIYccGH3p9K%20FSAwNUhDoSABJIIxGCBwADq0CMc0JcG1ppLJTl2j0hhM5ksNmLU%20Ke1ySAIBFrmMOsPrFe%20zdoZzQ-Mo4QA-KfBsN8ZNuaucZOn9O9YqEkZgGgANZxJA6u%20L5ToBs76MYZgWGgVjWMBsranmyiqJIkpBpadBAA)!  Yay!  Except...hold up.  It doesn't actually *do anything*.  All of that and it still doesn't work.  **I hate refs.  Refs are bad.**

### Using the Ref

We forwarded the ref to `MyCustomComponent`, who now has access to the forwarded ref and can attach it to a DOM component.  But we don't want it attached to the DOM element, we want it attached to `MyCustomComponent`.  But we can't really do that.

> By default, you may not use the ref attribute on function components because they don’t have instances [[docs]](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-function-components)

We have to make use of a hook called `useImperativeHandle` which feels like a hack solution and even the docs say "don't do this".  Yup, I hate refs.

> useImperativeHandle customizes the instance value that is exposed to parent components when using ref. **As always, imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases.** useImperativeHandle should be used with forwardRef. [[docs]](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)

We have to expose our `coolAlert` method through `useImperativeHandle`.

```
useImperativeHandle(ref , () => ({coolAlert}));
```

And now [it actually works](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-64488719-cw8qm?file=/src/App.tsx), finally!

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! By the way, when you say `useImperativeHandle`'s use is discouraged, I assume that as long as I'm using it with `forwardRef` it's fine?

Comment: It’s fine but it’s not great, if that makes sense.  Basically communication between react components is meant to go from the top down, where higher-up components pass callbacks down to their children and children communicate back to the parents by calling those callback functions.  What you want to be doing is declaring the coolAlert function in the parent and passing down to the child via props.  I don’t know what your actual code is, though I assume there’s a reason you’re doing it this way.  But there’s probably a way to reorganize it so that data flows from the top down.

Comment: Forwarding refs in general is discouraged.  It works but it’s sort of backwards.  You’ll hear the term “anti-pattern” used to describe code structures that are contrary to their intended use.  It is encouraged to control the child via props where possible.

Comment: I wanted to create a text editor and a toolbar, where the user is able to import the toolbar as a separate component. That's why I needed some sort of bridge between them for the toolbar to pass commands to the text editor. Perhaps writing a bridge or api of some sort would be a better solution.

Comment: You can also think about having a global application state through the react context API via redux or by using contexts directly (though the react docs tell you to avoid contexts when it’s not necessary too).  I have a tendency to rewrite everything a million times in search of the perfect code.  So on the one hand I’m like “I hate this” and on the other hand I’m like “Don’t be me.  Don’t burn your app down to the ground just because it’s not perfect.”  So yeah to be clear it’s not a problem it’s just a less than ideal design pattern.

Comment: @linda: I think I have a similar problem, you could take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65160748/react-native-ref-property-ref-does-not-exist-on-type-intrinsicattributes