# React native ref Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, ref, react-ref

I am getting the following error but I am not able to figure out how to fix it someone can help me out.

Below is also the link on expo with the complete code.

Error on `<AppIntroSlider />` which is reported by snack expo

[image]

Example:

[image]

> Type '{ ref: (ref: any) => any; data: { key: string; title: string;
> text: string; backgroundColor: string; }[]; renderItem: ({ item }:
> any) => Element; renderPagination: (activeIndex: number) => Element;
> scrollX: (scrollXList: any) => any; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & { data: any[]; renderItem: (info:
> ListRenderItemInfo & { dimensions: { width: number; height:
> number; }; }) => ReactNode; renderSkipButton?: (() => ReactNode) |
> undefined; ... 19 more ...; scrollX?: ((a: any) => void) | undefined;
> } & FlatListProps<...> & { ...; }'.   Property 'ref' does not exist on
> type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { data: any[]; renderItem: (info:
> ListRenderItemInfo & { dimensions: { width: number; height:
> number; }; }) => ReactNode; renderSkipButton?: (() => ReactNode) |
> undefined; ... 19 more ...; scrollX?: ((a: any) => void) | undefined;
> } & FlatListProps<...> & { ...; }'.

Link: [expo](https://snack.expo.io/iI_6XNg2f)

```js
  const slider = useRef(null);
  ...
  <AppIntroSlider
      ref={(ref: any) => (slider.current = ref)}
      ...
```

```
type ItemTProps<ItemT> = {
  data: ItemT[];
  renderItem: (
    info: ListRenderItemInfo<ItemT> & {
      dimensions: { width: number; height: number };
    }
  ) => React.ReactNode;
  renderSkipButton?: () => React.ReactNode;
  renderNextButton?: () => React.ReactNode;
  renderDoneButton?: () => React.ReactNode;
  renderPrevButton?: () => React.ReactNode;
  onSlideChange?: (a: number, b: number) => void;
  onSkip?: () => void;
  onDone?: () => void;
  renderPagination?: (activeIndex: number) => React.ReactNode;
  activeDotStyle: ViewStyle;
  dotStyle: ViewStyle;
  dotClickEnabled: boolean;
  skipLabel: string;
  doneLabel: string;
  nextLabel: string;
  prevLabel: string;
  showDoneButton: boolean;
  showNextButton: boolean;
  showPrevButton: boolean;
  showSkipButton: boolean;
  bottomButton: boolean;
  scrollX?: (a: any) => void;
} & FlatListProps<ItemT>;

const AppIntroSlider: FunctionComponent<ItemTProps<any>> = ({
  data,
  renderItem,
  renderSkipButton,
  renderNextButton,
  renderDoneButton,
  renderPrevButton,
  onSlideChange,
  onSkip,
  onDone,
  renderPagination,
  activeDotStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)',
  },
  dotStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)',
  },
  dotClickEnabled = true,
  skipLabel = 'Skip',
  doneLabel = 'Done',
  nextLabel = 'Next',
  prevLabel = 'Back',
  showDoneButton = true,
  showNextButton = true,
  showPrevButton = false,
  showSkipButton = false,
  bottomButton = false,
  extraData,
  scrollX,
  ...otherProps
}: any) => {
```

Comment: Your app in expo snack it works fine!

Comment: @Aymen: The next button does not work when you click, the problem is that I have to use the reference to the module, it is from that problem that I say.

I don't know if I've made myself clear.

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar: May I ask you if you could give me an example?
Inside the app I can't access the goToSlide method, which I should access via ref.

Answer (score 1):

When you log **slider.current** ref it displayed **null** because your **AppIntroSlider** component is a functional component and doesn't support this way. you have two solutions, change **AppIntroSlide** to a class component and it will work fine, or use **forwardRef**.

Comment: If I wanted to use forwardRef what should I do?

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: look at this explanation https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-refs-for-function-components-44f1a5a2332a

Comment: If I don't succeed by studying the guide you gave me, I can ask you if you could help me.
It would be very important to understand where I'm wrong and to be able to make it work.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `__slider$current.goToSlide is not a function. (In '_slider$current.goToSlide(activeIndex + 1, true)', '_slider$current.goToSlide' is undefined)` but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Link: https://snack.expo.io/vsrGzYEPA

Comment: I think I succeeded, but I'm not sure it's the best solution I had to use useImperativeHandle to show the method.

What do you think about it?

Link: https://snack.expo.io/FvTPa_kv3

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the example that you posted with `useImperativeHandle` and you've got it mostly right.  Your usage is a little different than the one [in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64491870/10431574) because your function `goToSlide` takes arguments.

When you define the `interface` for the referenced component, you need to define the `goToSlide` function with the appropriate argument types.  You currently defined it as a function that takes no arguments (`goToSlide(): void`) and that's why you are getting the error *"Type '(pageNum: number, triggerOnSlideChange?: boolean | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'."* on the line with `useImperativeHandle`.

```
export interface MyRef {
  goToSlide(pageNum: number, triggerOnSlideChange?: boolean): void;
}
```

A bunch of the props on `MyCustomComponentProps` should be defined as optional.  You are already setting default value for them.

After fixing those two things, all of your errors go away except for those caused by the optional chaining `?.`.  This is a new-ish feature and I'm not sure how to get Expo to understand it.

You don't technically *need* the `?.` after `sliderRef` because the ref object will always be defined.  It's the `current` property that might be `null`, so you do need the `?.` after `current`.  But you could also check it the old-fashioned way if the red underlines bother you:

```
const prev = (activeIndex: number): void => {
  if ( sliderRef.current ) {
    sliderRef.current.goToSlide(activeIndex - 1, true);
  }
};
```

[Updated expo link](https://snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/expo-typescript)

Comment: Thank you, I relied on your example to try to solve the problem.

Can I ask you any doubts I have and have not been able to solve them?