# How to access connected child component methods from parents in react typescript class component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using "connect" on the child component to interact with redux store(am using redux-toolkit). After importing the child component in parent component, I have created reference to the child component using `createRef` to access child component members.

Child component -->

```
class ChildComp extends React.Component<IReduxProps, IState>
{
}

default export connect(mapToState, mapToDispatch,null, { forwardRef: true })(ChildComp)
```

In parent component class

```
import ChildComp from './childCompFile'

class ParentComp extends React.Component<IReduxProps, IState> {
  childRef: React.RefObject<typeof ChildComp>;
  
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.childRef= React.createRef<typeof ChildComp>();
  }
  
  onChildClick = () => {
    this.childRef.current.showChildCompPanel();
  };

  render() {
    <Button onClick={this.onChildClick}></Button>
    <ChildComp ref={this.childRef}/>
  }
}
```

Am not able to access any of the methods in child class using `this.childRef.current.`
Please give an example to show how to access redux connected child class methods using ref from parent class

Comment: define the method at Parent instead, and pass down to Child. you don't pass methods upwards in React.

Comment: Yes the methods are used to change some state of child components like Show Panel state to turn on or off. Thats why its required

Comment: `ChildComp` is going to ignore the passed `ref` prop unless the `ChildComp` component is built to handle it using `forwardRef` and `useImperativeHandle`.  You can do that, but it's probably better to move the show panel state up to `ParentComp` and pass it down through props.  This explains the ref approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64491870/10431574

Comment: If you can provide a repo or a codesandbox I can take a look at it.  It's hard to see what's going awry from you've posted as there are some JSX errors and things that don't make sense to me, like why parent and child would have the same state interface.  The link I previously posted deals with function components but you are using class components which does make ref forwarding easier.  In its most basic version, your setup does work: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-stallman-sfgj9?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @LindaPaiste IReduxProps, IState refers to just an example. It can be different for parent or child. Thanks any way. From your code I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong. Appreciated.