# Calling a children method of a functional component from parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am not using class, I'd like to learn how to do it manually. I am dealing with login screen.
https://snack.expo.io/@ericsia/call-function-from-child-component
If you want to show me your code, you need to save and share the link. So I wanted a functional component for display textbox (assume `ChildComponent` as the function name, so `export ChildComponent`).
So in Parent/Screen1 I have something like this right?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import ChildComponent from './components/ChildComponent';

export default function App() {
  
  function checkSuccess()
  {
    // call helloWorld from here
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
   
        <ChildComponent />
    
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
        onPress={ checkSuccess } >
        <Text>helloWorld ChildComponent</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#DDDDDD",
    padding: 10
  },
});
```

so if the result is invalid right, I wanted to display a tiny red error message.
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwoyM.png)
My approach is if I can call a function from the `ChildComponent` then I may still solve it.
I googled it and most of the solution provided is for class.
I tried `useEffect` `React.createRef` `useImperativeHandle` but I didn't get it work.
for start, i am just trying to call the `helloWorld()`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { TextInput , View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function ChildComponent() {
  function helloWorld()
  {
    alert("Hello World");
  }
  return (<TextInput placeholder="Try to call helloWorld from App.js"/>);
}
```

Another question, if I have a textbox in my ChildComponent how do I retrieve the text/value from parent?

Comment: It's honestly a real pain to this.  You are much better off declaring `helloWorld` in the parent `App` and passing it down to `ChildComponent` as a prop.  My answer here explains how to do it the hard way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64491870/10431574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Easy Way: Passing Props

You can move the `helloWorld` function up to the parent component and pass it down to the child as a prop.  That way both components can call it.  I recommend using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) when you are going to be passing around a function, though it doesn't matter in this case.

Parent

```
export default function App() {
  const helloWorld = () => {
    alert('Hello World');
  }
  const checkSuccess = () => {
    helloWorld();
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ChildComponent helloWorld={helloWorld} />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={checkSuccess}>
        <Text>helloWorld ChildComponent</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Child

```
const ChildComponent = ({ helloWorld }) => {
  // could do anything with helloWorld here

  return <TextInput placeholder="Try to call helloWorld from App.js" />;
};
```

#### The Hard Way: Ref Forwarding

If you want to keep the function in the child component then you need to go through a lot of hoops.  I do not recommend this approach.

You have to do all of these steps:

- Create a `ref` object in the parent using [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref): `const childRef = React.useRef();`
- Pass the ref to the child as a prop: `<ChildComponent ref={childRef} />`
- Call the function on the current value of the child component ref, using `?.` to avoid errors if `.current` has not yet been set: `childRef.current?.helloWorld();`
- Accept the `ref` prop in the child by using [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html): `React.forwardRef( (props, ref) => {`
- Expose the `helloWorld` function as an instance variable of the child component by using [`useImperativeHandle`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle): `React.useImperativeHandle(ref , () => ({helloWorld}));`

Parent:

```
export default function App() {
  const childRef = React.useRef();

  function checkSuccess() {
    childRef.current?.helloWorld();
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ChildComponent ref={childRef} />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={checkSuccess}>
        <Text>helloWorld ChildComponent</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Child:

```
const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  function helloWorld() {
    alert('Hello World');
  }

  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ helloWorld }));

  return <TextInput placeholder="Try to call helloWorld from App.js" />;
});
```

Edit: [Expo Link](https://snack.expo.io/P61KJDOKr)

Comment: it is not as simple as helloWorld, you see if the input is wrong right, I'd like to show a visible red text beneath the textbox, so the function must be in the ChildComponent

Comment: I tried the useImperative but it failed, but I deeply appreciated your detail guide. if possible you can try from the link above, save it and share the link

Comment: sure: https://snack.expo.io/P61KJDOKr  I didn't include typescript annotations since you weren't using typescript in the original.

Comment: You are awesome, that's amazing. But I didn't seem to able to get typescript version working. Anyway thanks a lot!!

Comment: Another question, if I have a textbox in my ChildComponent what is the elegant way to retrieve the text/value from parent?

Comment: Hey!  I didn’t use typescript types in my Expo because you were using .JS and not .TSX files in your original.  I can definitely rewrite it in typescript but I’ve got limited internet right now!  As far as passing info from the parent to the child, that’s always easier so you would just use props for that.

Comment: Does this help? https://snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/call-function-from-child-component

Comment: yes, it sure does. Lot of loves from me, thank you so much!! You are awesome!

Comment: In ChildComponent line 33 I saw you call something like this ` childFunc,` what is that?

Comment: Ok so I am passing two versions of the function to the ref, one that takes a `value` argument and one that takes no arguments (and will be called with the `childVal`).  Inside of `useImperativeHandle` you return an object that maps the props to their value.  The value for `childFunc` is the function `childFunc` so you can just include the name, but `childFunc: childFunc,` would be the same.  The value for `callChildFunc` is a function that takes no arguments, so I am using an inline arrow function to define its value as `() => childFunc(childVal)`.  But you could create an actual function too.