# React native typeScript and forwardRef in a functional component

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I'm in react native app an I use typeScript too.
I have a functional component :

```
const Input: React.FunctionComponent<IInputProps> = ({
  inputStyle,
  placeHolderColor = EAppColors.DARK_GREY,
  placeHolder,
  value,
  onChangeText,
  autoFocus,
  onFocus,
  onBlur,
  onSubmitEditing,
  ref,
  keyboardType = EKeyboardType.DEFAULT,
}) => {
  return (
    <StyledInput
      testID="TextInputID"
      placeholderTextColor={placeHolderColor}
      placeholder={placeHolder}
    ...
```

I create some ref for different input before my render:

```
const firstNameRef = React.createRef<TextInput>();
    const lastNameRef = React.createRef<TextInput>();
    const birthDateRef = React.createRef<TextInput>();
```

and I use after this component in a class like that :

```
<StyledTextInput
                label={I18n.t('auth.heading.firstNameLabel')}
                errorText={errorText}
                ref={firstNameRef}
                autoFocus={true}
                placeHolder={I18n.t('auth.placeHolder.firstName')}
                isFocused={focusOnFirstFields}
                hasError={hasError}
                onFocus={() => this.setState({ focusOnFirstFields: true })}
                onBlur={() => this.setState({ focusOnFirstFields: false })}
                showClearButton={showFirstClearButton}
                value={firstName}
                onClearText={() => this.onClearText(1)}
                onChangeText={(value: string) =>
                  this.setState({
                    firstName: value,
                    disabled: false,
                    showFirstClearButton: true,
                  })
                }
                onSubmitEditing={() => {
               if (lastNameRef !== null && lastNameRef.current !== null) {
                     lastNameRef.current.focus();
                  }
                }}
                keyboardType={EKeyboardType.DEFAULT}
              />
```

But when I want to use  **onSubmitEditing** for focus the next input, I have this error :
[image]

How can I resolve this issue ?
Thank You!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use forwardRef with FunctionComponent in React Native using TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64488719/how-to-use-forwardref-with-functioncomponent-in-react-native-using-typescript)

Comment: thank you @Fuze-Mcsea but no :( 
ps: I have edit my question would be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef</* type of ref*/HTMLButtonElement, /* component props */ComponentProps>((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>))
```

It will be correctly typed as

```
const FancyButton: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<React.RefAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>>
```

(You don't need to use `React.FunctionComponent` when using forwardRef).

```
const Input = React.forwardRef<TextInput, IInputProps>(({
  inputStyle,
  placeHolderColor = EAppColors.DARK_GREY,
  placeHolder,
  value,
  onChangeText,
  autoFocus,
  onFocus,
  onBlur,
  onSubmitEditing,
  keyboardType = EKeyboardType.DEFAULT,
}, ref /* <--- ref is passed here!!*/) => {
   // assuming this is a TextInput
  return (
    <StyledInput
      ref={ref}
      testID="TextInputID"
      placeholderTextColor={placeHolderColor}
      placeholder={placeHolder}
    ... 
})
```

Comment: thank you @jperl  I have edit my question would be more clear ....
I have steel an error

Comment: @E.D I don't see forwardRef anywhere. That's what the error is telling you.

Comment: @E.D I have updated my answer. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I tried with your exemple but when with this code :
```javascript
const Input: React.forwardRef<TextInput, IInputProps> = ({
  inputStyle,
  placeHolderColor = EAppColors.DARK_GREY,
  placeHolder,
  value,
  onChangeText,
  autoFocus,
  onFocus,
  onBlur,
  onSubmitEditing,
  ref,
  keyboardType = EKeyboardType.DEFAULT,
}) => {
  return (...
```  
I have some erros with my props :
**Binding element 'placeHolder' implicitly has an 'any' type**
or **Cannot find name 'ref'**

Comment: You need to remove 'ref', it's passed a a second prop, have a look at the example.

Comment: there is my IInputPorps: 
```javascript
interface IInputProps {
  readonly placeHolderColor?: string;
  readonly placeHolder?: string;
  readonly inputStyle?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  readonly value: string;
  readonly onChangeText: (value: string) => void;
  readonly onFocus?: () => void;
  readonly onBlur?: () => void;
  readonly onSubmitEditing?: () => void;
  readonly keyboardType?: EKeyboardType;
  readonly autoFocus: boolean;
  readonly ref?: RefObject<TextInput>;
}

```

Comment: I have remove ref from IInputProps but I steel have error for the ref argument (**Cannot find name 'ref'.ts(2304)
Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.**) and for my props

Comment: I forgot some parentheses, sorry. Could you try one more time please? (I have updated my answer)

Comment: nope  same error (I updated the error picture)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231320/discussion-between-jperl-and-e-d).

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem a few months ago. I solved it by doing:

```
   import {TextInputProps, TextInput} from 'react-native';

   type IProps = TextInputProps & {
      labelText?: string;
    };
    
    const TextInputStd: React.FC<IProps> = React.forwardRef(
      (
        {
          labelText,
          ...textInputProps
        }: IProps,
        ref: React.Ref<TextInput>,
      ) => {
        const {styles} = useStyles(_styles);
    
        return (
          <>
            <View style={[styles.textInputContainer, styles2.textInputContainer]}>
              <Text style={styles.labelText}>{labelText || ''}</Text>
              <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
                <TextInput style={styles.input} {...textInputProps} ref={ref} />
              </View>
            </View>
          </>
        );
      },
    );
```

Hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Fuze-Mcsea I solved my issue with a precedent response in the same way ;)

Answer (score -2):

not 100% sure what the question is here, but

```
<StyledInput
  ref={ref}
  testID="TextInputID"
  placeholderTextColor={placeHolderColor}
  placeholder={placeHolder}
  ...
```

should work, then you need to pass the ref in when calling this input.